# Basic Three.js template scene, can´t animate

Tags: three.js

I'm really new in Three.js and javascript in general.

My question, I'm been trying to create some king of basic frankenstein template ( mainly based on Lee Stemkoski's examples) to use Three.js but as right know i can't make the cube spin infinitely, I have been watching tutorials and other examples but i can't make it work, any ideas why or how to solve it?

And

Any suggestions on how to improve this template scene?

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>three.js Template</title>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/DDSLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
        <script src="js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
        <script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="info">
            <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> Template Scene<br />
            from <a href="x">Base scene</a>
        </div>

        <div id="threeJSScene"></div>

        <script>



// MAIN //

// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats, animate;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

// initialization
init();
// animation loop / game loop
animate();

// FUNCTIONS //


function init() 
{

    // SCENE //

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Add fog to the scene
//  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.001 );

    // CAMERA //

    // set the view size in pixels (custom or according to window size)
    // var SCREEN_WIDTH = 400, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300;
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight; 
    // camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    // set up camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    // add the camera to the scene
    scene.add(camera);
    // the camera defaults to position (0,0,0)
    //  so pull it back (z = 400) and up (y = 100) and set the angle towards the scene origin
    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  



    // RENDERER //

    // create and start the renderer; choose antialias setting.
    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha:true, antialias:true} );
    else
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 

    // Configure renderer size
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //Change BG Color
    //renderer.setClearColor( 0xAA20AA );

    //Configure pixel aspect ratio
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

    //Enable shadows
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

    // Modify gamma
    // renderer.gammaInput = true;
    // renderer.gammaOutput = true;

    //Attach div element to variable to contain the renderer
    container = document.getElementById( 'threeJSScene' );
    // alternatively: to create the div at runtime, use:
    //   container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    //    document.body.appendChild( container );

    // attach renderer to the *container* div
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    // EVENTS //

    // automatically resize renderer
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    // toggle full-screen on given key press
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });


    // CONTROLS //

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // remove when using animation loop
                // enable animation loop when using damping or autorotation
                //controls.enableDamping = true;
                //controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
                controls.enableZoom = true;
                //controls.update(); ----------> // required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true 


    // STATS //

    // displays current and past frames per second attained by scene
    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );


    // LIGHT //

    // Add ambient light to Scene - Color(Blue) - Intensity
    var Ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x506699, 1);
    scene.add(Ambientlight);

    // Add light to Scene - Color(Red) - Intensity - Distance - decay
    var light1 = new THREE.PointLight (0xff0000, 2, 400, 2);
    light1.position.set(-60,150,-30);
    light1.castShadow = true;
    light1.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    light1.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024 * 2; 
    light1.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024 * 2;
    light1.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
    light1.shadow.camera.near = 20;      
    light1.shadow.camera.far = 10000;     
    scene.add(light1);   

    // spotlight #1 -- yellow, dark shadow
    var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffff00);
    spotlight.position.set(-60,150,-30);
    spotlight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
    spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
    spotlight.intensity = 2;
    // must enable shadow casting ability for the light
    spotlight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(spotlight);


    // GEOMETRY //

    // Create a Cube Mesh //
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );

    // Create a basic material
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
    color: "#ffffff",
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    //transparent: true,
    //opacity: 0.5,
    //wireframe: true,
    //wireframeLinewidth: 5, 
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/pattern.jpg'),
    normalMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/pattern_NRM.png')
    });

    //Join the two attribute ( Geometry and material ) 
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    mesh.position.set(0, 50, 0); // Chance object position  
    //Add geometry to the scene

    scene.add (mesh);

    // Create a TorusKnot //
    var TorusknotGeometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 15, 5, 60, 25 );
    var Torusknot = new THREE.Mesh( TorusknotGeometry, material); // We are using the same material created for the cube
    Torusknot.castShadow = true;
    Torusknot.receiveShadow = true;
    Torusknot.position.set (0,100,0);
    scene.add (Torusknot);

    // Create a cube for the ground //
    var groundGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200,200,10);
    var ground = new THREE.Mesh( groundGeometry, material);
    ground.castShadow = true;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;
    ground.position.set (0,0,0);
    ground.rotation.x = 1.57;

    scene.add (ground);


    // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
      var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      loader.load( "models/treehouse_logo.js", function(log){
        var materiallogo = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
        logo = new THREE.Mesh(log, materiallogo);
        logo.scale.set (50,50,50);
        logo.position.y = -1;
        logo.castShadow = true;
        logo.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(logo);
      });

    // FLOOR //

    // note: 4x4 checkboard pattern scaled so that each square is 25 by 25 pixels.
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/checkerboard.jpg' );
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    // DoubleSide: render texture on both sides of mesh
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 1, 1);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.castShadow = true;
    floor.receiveShadow = true;
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(floor);



    // create a set of coordinate axes to help orient user
    //    specify length in pixels in each direction
    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
    scene.add( axes );

    // SKY //

    // recommend either a skybox or fog effect (can't use both at the same time) 
    // without one of these, the scene's background color is determined by webpage background
    // make sure the camera's "far" value is large enough so that it will render the skyBox!
    var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
    // BackSide: render faces from inside of the cube, instead of from outside (default).
    var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
    // scene.add(skyBox);
}
 function update()
{   
    controls.update();
    stats.update();

}           
//Animate function            
function animate() 
{

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();       
    update();
}

// Render the scene - Always goes at the end          
function render() 
{   
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked in your developer console? Does it give an error message?

Comment: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/) is a template I use for fiddles with three.js

Comment: I have try it, but as soon as I add the code in the animate function the scene goes black, how shoud I add it to my scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate your cube you'll need to add some value to the cube's rotation every frame. The reason this didn't work when you did it before is that the `cube` is defined in your init function and the `render` function doesn't have a reference to it.

So your fix requires two things:

- Define your cube in a scope that both methods can "see"
- Add some value to the rotation of your cube every frame

Inside of the init function you're defining your cube as `mesh`, so rename this to `cube` and remove `var`:

```
//Join the two attribute ( Geometry and material ) 
//var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);  // Old  
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material); // new
```

Removing `var` causes `cube` to become a global variable defined on the dom `window` rather than the `init` function. So your render function can "see" `cube`. So now all you have to do is rotate it!

```
function render() 
{   
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

I hope that helps!
and if you'd like to learn more about scope give this link a good read, it's helped me quite a bit.
https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Awesome, great explanation, Thanks that's fix the problem, so I should never use Var for a object?

Comment: Global variables are bad practice in general, spend some time getting familiar with scoped variables. It'll make your life real easy :D

Answer (score 0):

I ctrl + f'd the code, and you don't reference the rotation of the cube once. That would explain why it's not rotating. You can't *will it to rotate*, you need to actually write something that will change the values of the elements in your scene.

In order to continuously change the rotation of something, you need to reference or increment its rotation in the part of the code that loops.

Comment: I already try something like this but didn't work

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.05;
 render();
 update();  
}

The scene just goes black

Comment: when it goes black, open the inspector for your browser, reload the page, and tell me what it says in the console. if it's black, there is probably an error, so it doesn't matter what your code is until the error gets resolved. It might have nothing to do with your rotation code.